# How can I optimize the runtime of an algorithm that ranks binned columns cumulatively by average of another column?

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I have a dense set of data that looks like this

| Y | X1_BIN1 | X1_BIN2 | X2_BIN1 | X2_BIN2 | X2_BIN3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | ... |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | ... |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | ... |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | ... |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... |

but for millions of rows and about 400 columns, corresponding to bins of about 20 different XN variables. The average of Y is about 0.01.

What I want to do, is select the bin (e.g., X1_BIN1, X2_BIN3) that has the highest average Y value (always 1 or 0), then remove those rows, and then repeat the process until all rows have been selected or all remaining Y values are 0.

In the above example, X2_BIN1 would be chosen first, the second row would be removed, then X2_BIN2 would be chosen second, and all the remaining rows would be 0.

The problem with my current method is that it searches through all columns of data after each iteration, and then selects the one with the highest average. This has an O(N^2) runtime, which is bad when I have about 400 columns to go through.

Unfortunately, I can't think of any surefire way that would effectively reduce the runtime of this process.

For very small bins, I can subtract the count of the bin from all the other bins, and see if there are any others/groups of any others, with that subtracted count, that would still have a higher rate than the remaining bins with their original count. I think that this would save maybe one or two iterations out of hundreds, though, and

If I only calculate bins that would still have enough rows after removing K rows in a previous iteration, the average rate is so low that I could only assume the average Y value for bins that are mutually exclusive from the previous bin (e.g., if I remove X1_BIN1, then the average of X1_BIN2 is the same for the entire set). And then I would need to recalculate those bins if rows corresponding to a bin of another X variable were removed.

Additionally, the bins are constructed in a way that they are all likely to have distinct average values within a given X variable, making the above more effort than it's worth.

I'm not sure if this is better suited towards a more statistics-oriented forum, since there are underlying distributions that would make certain approaches better, but at this point, I feel like I've mostly used statistics just to rule solutions out.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n$ and $m$+1 be the number of rows and columns, respectively (so that there are $m$ bins). Your problem can solved in $O(nm + m^2)$ time.
This is asymptotically optimal unless $m = \Omega(n)$, i.e., you have asymptotically more bins than rows.

Maintain the following:

- A collection of lists $L_1, \dots, L_m$ where $L_j$ stores all rows contained in the $j$-th bin.
- An array of Booleans $R[1, \dots, n]$ where $R[i]$ is true if and only if the $i$-th row has already been selected. Initially all $R[i]$s are false.
- An array $A[1, \dots, m]$ where $A[j]$ contains the number of unselected rows that belong to the $j$-th bin and have $Y$ set to $1$. (Initially no row is selected).
- An array $B[j]$ that contains the number of unselected rows that belong to the $j$-th bin. Initially $B[j] = |L_j|$.

Repeat the following:

- Find the index $j$ of a bin such that $A[j]>0$ and $A[j]/B[j]$ is maximized. If no such index exists we are done.
- For each row $i$ in $L_j$ such that $R[i]$ is false:

  - Set $R[i]$ to true
  - For each bin $h = 1, \dots, m$:

    - If row $i$ belongs to bin $h$:

      - Decrement $B[h]$ by $1$
      - If the $Y$ value of row $i$ is $1$:

        - Decrement $A[h]$

Let's bound the time complexity of this algorithm.
Finding the next bin $j$ to process takes $O(m)$ time and happens at most $m$ times, therefore the overall time spent during this step is $O(m^2)$.
For a fixed bin $j$, the time spent iterating over $L_j$ to find the rows $i$ to process is $O(n)$, therefore the overall time spent across all bins is $O(nm)$ .
Moreover, each row is processed only once, in time $O(m)$. The overall time is hence $O(nm)$.